# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager - no activity listed

Tags: android

I'm using Crittercism to track crashes in my app. I encountered one I don't know how to handle.

That's the Crittersim log:

**Crashed Thread**

```
0   
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
1   
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:656)
2   
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:349)
3   
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:160)
4   
at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController.setVisible(ZoomButtonsController.java:407)
5   
at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$2.handleMessage(ZoomButtonsController.java:179)
6   
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
7   
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
8   
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
9   
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
12  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
13  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
27 other threads
```

**Thread: AsyncTask #4 (id=721, state=WAITING)**

```
0   
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
1   
java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
2   
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
3   
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
4   
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
5   
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
6   
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
7   
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
8   
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
9   
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**Thread: ImageContentLoader_Cache (id=709, state=RUNNABLE)**

```
0   
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
1   
android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
2   
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
3   
android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

**Thread: pool-4-thread-1 (id=695, state=WAITING)**

```
0   
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
1   
java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
2   
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
3   
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
4   
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
5   
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
6   
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
7   
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
8   
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
9   
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**Thread: Request worker thread (id=707, state=RUNNABLE)**

```
0   
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
1   
android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
2   
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
3   
com.[XXXXXXX].android.services.ServerTalk.run(ServerTalk.java:2043)
4   
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

There is only one reference to my app:

**com.[XXXXXXX].android.services.ServerTalk.run(ServerTalk.java:2043)**

which lead to this line:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    Looper.prepare();
    synchronized (this)
    {
        if (mCanRunLooper)
        {
            mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
            mRequestHandler = new RequestThreadHandler();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    mEvent.open();
    Looper.loop();  <----- [HERE]

}
```

This ServerTalk is a service that handles web requests and is being called by various activities. The problem is that none of the activities are ever listed here and in fact my app is not even listed in the thread that actually crashed. This crash happened multiple times, but I can't replicate it myself. I have no clue what this is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"View not attached to window manager" means it's not an active view in the hierarchy. A little further in the stack you see "ZoomButtonsController.setVisible".

You say ServerTalk is a service. Why is it trying to call a method on a view? Services can't have UI.